# How can I print out the second word from each line of a file in powershell?

Tags: powershell

For example: sample.txt contains:

```
John Doe data
Jane Doe data
```

An the output would be:

```
Doe
Doe
```

I've tried `(Get-Content sample.txt).Split(' ')[1]` but that doesn't work since it prints the second word of the first line only (second element of the array).

Output:

```
Doe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.Split()` (and index into the result) *on each line* read by `Get-Content`, such as with the [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach):

```bash
(Get-Content sample.txt).ForEach({ $_.Split(' ')[1] })
```

If there's a chance that *multiple* spaces separate the words on a line, you can use the unary form of PowerShell's [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) *operator* instead:

```bash
(Get-Content sample.txt).ForEach({ (-split $_)[1] })
```

The streaming alternative, using the pipeline and the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*:

```bash
Get-Content sample.txt | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(' ')[1] }
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```bash
> (Get-Content sample.txt).Split(' ')[1]
> ```

- Thanks to [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), the `.Split()` call is applied to *each line* of the array of lines returned by [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content).
- Each `.Split()` call in turn returns an array.
- Member-access enumeration *concatenates* these arrays to form a single, flat array containing the words across all lines.
- Your `[1]` index is then applied only *once*, namely to this flat array, and returns its second element only (only the *first* line's second word).